# Double number IDs

Tags: mysql, facebook, auto-increment

I was wondering how facebook stores comments with IDs since there must be like a really high number of comments and messages in general, so I inspected the source and noticed that comments' IDs have two numbers, for example `530409847013982_5029288`. Can somebody explain how that works? I mean how are they being picked up and how are they being inserted, I'm not sure auto increment works this way?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Is it to implement this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @davidstrachan `Is it to implement this?` No, I'm just curious as to how this works?

Comment: Curiosity *is* a good thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer explain it, those kind of ID are hierarchical. This is probably some kind of composite key. To "speak MySQL" `UNIQUE(page_id, post_id)`. Which go back to your question:

> there must be like a really high number of comments and messages

Big numbers! But, according to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (or the *almost* equivalent `SERIAL` type) could hold values from 0 up to 18446744073709551615. Based on your example, and roughly speaking, there is still "room" for something like *10000 times* more messages.

If that wasn't enough, database usually provide a fixed point type ([`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)). With MySQL this type could hold up to 65 *base 10* digits. Clearly some space left!

Concerning the keys, MySQL limit these to [3072 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) using InnoDB tables (as a reference, `BIGINT` require 8 bytes).Largely enough for that kind of application.

*If* Facebook use MySQL, I don't think the ID/key length is there primary concern. I'm not sure they use MySQL thought? :D

Comment: `I'm not sure they use MySQL thought` why not?

Comment: @php_nub_qq That's a real statement: I'm not *sure* they use MySQL. Perhaps they do. Perhaps not. I didn't take time to check that. But if you did, I'll be happy to edit the answer accordingly ;)

Comment: I thought you knew they weren't and you were just laying it down politely. :D

Comment: @php_nub_qq To be precise, I *once* had a student that did a presentation on "Facebook technology" for her graduation exam. She didn't quite understand all she talk about -- and maybe all of this is a little bit outdated but as far as I remember, the basic concept to handle such a large amount of data what to only use "key-value store". MySQL was there, but only used as a *data store*  (*no* join or complex query). And one key feature was to use *memcached* to cache most of the data on commodity hardware in order to keep the load on the DB servers at acceptable levels.

Comment: I shouldn't have thought that they would use simple technology you can learn by googling "how to build a website" `:D`

Comment: @php_nub_qq It is not the tools that make you great. This is the way you use them. Apparently, they use them ... pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

The part prior to the underscore is the page id. The part after is the post id.

https://www.facebook.com/pageid/posts/postid